# Changing displayed <li> by clicking on another object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make simple information board with changing info by clicking on arrows.

Code:

```
<ul id="wybieraniekamienia">
    <li class="wybranykamien">Wcześniejszy kamień<br>Uruchomienie produkcji modelu<br><br>11.09.2013</li>
    <li class="wybranykamien kamiennumberone">"Zephyr"<br>Uruchomienie produkcji modelu<br><br>11.09.2013</li>
    <li class="wybranykamien">Późniejszy kamień<br>Uruchomienie produkcji modelu<br><br>11.09.2013</li>
</ul>
```

kamiennumberone is selected (displayed info as a default), and now by click on arrows i want to change info on next() or prev().

Jquery:

```
$('#strzalkaprawa').click(function(){
    $('.kamiennumberone').toggle();
    $('.kamiennumberone').next(li).toggle();
});
```

I tried also to get to the next object before hiding it:

```
var nextone = $('.kamiennumberone').next(li);
$('.kamiennumberone').toggle();
$(nextone).toggle();
```

but it doesnt work. How i can get to the next objec if im hidding it?

Comment: I assume your button has that id `strzalkaprawa`?

And what version of jQuery are you using? (just to test it)

Comment: So not selected LIs are hidden or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
$('.kamiennumberone').next(li).toggle();
```

`li` is a variable name. You meant to use a string:

```
$('.kamiennumberone').next('li').toggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/RWW5q/

---

If you want to rotate through the entire list, you need to use `.toggleClass()` instead of `.toggle()` (and a little extra code):

```
$('#strzalkaprawa').click(function () {
    $a = $('.kamiennumberone').toggleClass('kamiennumberone');
    $b = $a.next('li');
    if (!$b.length) { // we went past the end of the list
        $b = $a.siblings().first();
    }
    $b.toggleClass('kamiennumberone');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/6Qru4/

Comment: Still dont know how to do it :/

$('#strzalkaprawa').click(function () {
    $('#paseknr2').stop().animate({'left':"-=143"},1000);
    $a = $('.kamiennumberone').toggleClass('kamiennumberone');
    $b = $a.next('li');
    if (!$b.length) {
        $b = $a.siblings().first();
    }
    $b.toggleClass('kamiennumberone');
});

That code doesnt change info :/

Comment: Did you see the CSS I used in the jsfiddle? I had to assume you had some similar styles in your own code, but perhaps I was wrong.